# Which verb does 下すった come from?

Tags: words

I came across this sentence while reading this [book](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000361/files/58199_69586.html) and I have my doubts regarding  下すった. Does it come from the verb 下す? Personally, I think it does, but is 下した not the past of 下す? Why 下すった？

> 「神様の授けて**下すった**ものを、神様がお召しになったのだ。神様からのがれることは出来ない」

Answer (score 3):

It's a variant of くださった in [nonstandard Tokyo dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_dialect) (江戸弁).

- くださった → くだすった
- くださって → くだすって
- なさった → なすった
- なさって → なすって

Few people speak like this in reality today, but I think this is common in samurai dramas, rakugo, and novels from the Meiji era to the early Showa era.

くだす is not relevant; the past form of くだす is くだした.

Comment: Gracias for the answer. Incidentally, what do you mean by "くだす is not relevant"?

Comment: @davidpolygoth Perhaps I should have said "下す is not related to this sentence"?

Comment: I see. Graciela, once again.